# Post two statements into database

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to insert two statements into my sql database. But when I click on send I see that only the first statement is posted.

Does someone know whats wrong with my code and how I can solve it?

Here is my code:

```
$query1 = "INSERT INTO table1(firstname, lastname) VALUES (?, ?)";
$stmt1 = $db->prepare($query1);
$stmt1->execute(array($firstname, $lastname));

$query2 = "INSERT INTO table2(firstname, lastname) VALUES (?, ?)";
$stmt2 = $db->prepare($query2);
$stmt2->execute(array($firstname, $lastname));
```

Comment: Do a check on the second execute statement.  And get the error

Comment: thanks @Akintunde sorry I haven't seen

Comment: @Akintunde The second statement is working in phpmyadmin

Answer (score 0):

you cannot always assume that your query would always work. There are many reasons for query failures. Whenever you execute a query, you must check to see if everything went OK. ALso turn on error reporting as well as checking your error logs. The issue should also be reported there

The below modification would help in filtering out the problem for the query failure

```
<?php
   error_reporting(E_ALL);

    $query2 = "INSERT INTO table2(`firstname`, `lastname`) VALUES (?, ?)";
    $stmt2 = $db->prepare($query2);
    if($stmt2->execute(array($firstname, $lastname))){//check if it saved
      echo 'Saved';
    } else {
      echo 'Failed Because '.$stmt2->error;//Oops something happened
    }
```

Comment: I am getting a browser error "This page isn’t working"

Answer (score 0):

Try this ==>

```
$query1 = "INSERT INTO table1(firstname, lastname) VALUES (?, ?)";
$stmt1 = $db->prepare($query1);
$stmt1->bind_param("ss",$firstname, $lastname);
$stmt1->execute();

$query2 = "INSERT INTO table2(firstname, lastname) VALUES (?, ?)";
$stmt2 = $db->prepare($query2);
$stmt2->bind_param("ss",$firstname, $lastname);
$stmt2->execute();
```

check more about [PHP Prepared Statements](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_prepared_statements.asp) here

Comment: `$query1` and `$query2` are both working when I try them seperated

Answer (score 0):

When you `prepare` a sql statement you can check that everything is OK before attempting to execute the sql and then, by assigning a variable to the result of the `execute` method, check that there was a successful query and proceed to the next statement.

```
Two very basic tables - identical except in name.

mysql> describe table1;
+-----------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field     | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-----------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| firstname | varchar(50) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| lastname  | varchar(50) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+-----------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+

mysql> describe table2;
+-----------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field     | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-----------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| firstname | varchar(50) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| lastname  | varchar(50) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+-----------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+




mysql> select * from table1;select * from table2;
+------------------------+-----------------------+
| firstname              | lastname              |
+------------------------+-----------------------+
| firstname59365bf480611 | lastname59365bf480613 |
+------------------------+-----------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

+------------------------+-----------------------+
| firstname              | lastname              |
+------------------------+-----------------------+
| firstname59365bf480611 | lastname59365bf480613 |
+------------------------+-----------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)





$firstname=uniqid('firstname');
$lastname=uniqid('lastname');



$dbhost =   'localhost';
$dbuser =   'root'; 
$dbpwd  =   ''; 
$dbname =   '';
$db     =   new mysqli( $dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpwd, $dbname );




$result = false;

$sql='insert into `table1` (`firstname`, `lastname`) values (?, ?)';
$stmt = $db->prepare( $sql );

if( $stmt ){

    $stmt->bind_param('ss',$firstname, $lastname );
    $result = $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->free_result();
    $stmt->close();

} else {
    exit( 'Error: Statement #1' );
}
if( $result ){

    $sql='insert into `table2` (`firstname`, `lastname`) values (?, ?)';
    $stmt = $db->prepare( $sql );

    if( $stmt ){

        $stmt->bind_param('ss',$firstname, $lastname );
        $result = $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->free_result();
        $stmt->close();

    } else {
        exit( 'Error: Statement #2' );
    }
}
$db->close();
```

Comment: I am getting a browser error "This page isn’t working"

Comment: oops, forgot to `prepare` 2nd statement

Comment: I am trying to run just the first statement. But still have the page error. When I try my own code it works

Comment: I have this exact code set as a test and it works ( now that I have included the 2nd `prepare` statement )

Comment: Thats really weard. I have exactly the same code (with the backtricks, spaces etc.) but still getting the "This page isn’t working" error. I also tried on another browser but I have the same there

Comment: My hosting provider updates the error logs once per day. I can see the error logs tomorrow